# MOP 2011 inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality, uvw

If $a,b,c$ are positive integers prove that

> $\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2)} +\sqrt{(b^2+c^2-bc)} +\sqrt{(a^2+c^2-ac)} +9(abc)^{1/3} \le 4(a+b+c)$

My attempt:

I tried to split inequality and prove it bit by bit

$9(abc)^{1/3} \le 3(a+b+c)$
It suffices to prove that

$\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2)} +\sqrt{(b^2+c^2-bc)} +\sqrt{(a^2+c^2-ac)} \le a+b+c$

After trying out few values I realized it is wrong.So I decided to tackle it all at your once. I tried few well known inequalities and played around but nothing came useful out of it. Any help??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way.

By AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}\leq\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2-ab+b^2}{a+b}+\frac{a+b}{4}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2-3ab}{a+b}+\frac{a+b}{4}\right)=\frac{5}{2}(a+b+c)-3\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a+b}=$$
$$=4(a+b+c)-3\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{ab}{a+b}+\frac{a+b}{4}\right)\leq$$
$$\leq 4(a+b+c)-3\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{ab}\leq4(a+b+c)-9\sqrt[3]{abc}.$$

Comment: Very nice! But I think it's hard to see the first line to use AM-GM: $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}\leq\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2-ab+b^2}{a+b}+\frac{a+b}{4}\right)$, do you have any idea to use it? Thanks.

Comment: @tthnew I don't agree. It's very smooth: $\frac{a^2-ab+b^2}{a+b}+\frac{a+b}{4}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{a^2-ab+b^2}{a+b}\cdot\frac{a+b}{4}}=\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}.$

Comment: I mean $\frac{a+b}{4}$ is bit of hard to find with me! You proof is nice, +1!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg  what is your motivation to specifically use 4 as denominator??

Comment: @Mathematical Curiosity The equality in the starting inequality occurs for $a=b=c$ and in AM-GM the equality occurs for equality case of variables. Thus, for $a=b$ we need $\frac{a^2-ab+b^2}{a+b}=k(a+b),$ which gives $k=\frac{1}{4}.$

Answer (score 3):

Using $\sum $ to denote cyclic sums,
\begin{align}
\sum \sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2} \;+ 9\sqrt[3]{abc} &\leqslant \sum \left(\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}+3\sqrt{ab}\right) \tag{*}\\
&\leqslant \sum 2(a+b) \tag{**}\\
&=4\sum a
\end{align}

---

Notes: * AM-GM inequality  ** Jensen's inequality with the concave function $t \mapsto\sqrt{t}$

Answer (score 0):

By Jensen $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}\leq3\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-ab+b^2)}{3}}=\sqrt{3\sum_{cyc}(2a^2-ab)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sqrt{3\sum_{cyc}(2a^2-ab)}+9\sqrt[3]{abc}\leq4(a+b+c).$$
Now, by $uvw$ (see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791 )

it's enough to prove the last inequality for equality case of two variables.

Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

As we can see that the term $9(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is difficult to deal with, we consider the following inequality $$-\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2)} -\sqrt{(b^2+c^2-bc)} -\sqrt{(a^2+c^2-ac)} +4(a+b+c)\ge 9(abc)^{1/3}.$$
Then we consider $$\frac{a+b}{2}-\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2)}=\frac{(\frac{a+b}{2})^2-(a^2-ab+b^2)}{\frac{a+b}{2}+\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2)}},$$the numerator is non-positive, and the denominator $$\frac{a+b}{2}+\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2)}\ge \frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a+b}{2}.$$So we have $$\frac{(\frac{a+b}{2})^2-(a^2-ab+b^2)}{\frac{a+b}{2}+\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2)}}\ge \frac{(\frac{a+b}{2})^2-(a^2-ab+b^2)}{a+b}=\frac{3ab}{a+b}-\frac{3}{4}(a+b).$$ Hence $$-\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2)} -\sqrt{(b^2+c^2-bc)} -\sqrt{(a^2+c^2-ac)} +4(a+b+c)\ge \sum_{cyc} \frac{3ab}{a+b}+\frac{3}{2}\sum a.$$Then you just need to use AM-GM inequality to prove it is greater than $9(abc)^{1/3}$.

One of my schoolmate of lower grade also finds a solution(before me).With the permission of him, I post his solution as follows:$$2(a+b)-\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}=\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}+\frac{3(a+b)}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}$$$$=\frac{a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{3ab}{a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}}\ge 3\sqrt{ab}$$
So sum up and use AM-GM, we can finish the proof.